# Configuring a Lambda function(Ruby) to access Amazon RDS(mysql) and do CRUD operations

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to configure lambda function to access RDS db(mysql) using Ruby code. I found one [blog](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2018/02/aws-lambda-function-with-rds-mysql.html) which is doing same but it's in python. Can anyone help me how we can do it using Ruby code?

Comment: Show your work plz sir

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've been doing your diligence work of creating a ruby project according to the lambda guidelines on Amazon (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-ruby.html) it's a matter of creating a `Gemfile` and in here add the gem `mysql2`.

An example of what you're looking for might be like this.

```
require 'json'
require 'mysql2'

$client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  host: ENV["DB_HOST"],
  username: ENV["DB_USER"],
  password: ENV["DB_PASSWORD"],
  database: ENV["DB_NAME"],
  port: ENV["DB_PORT"]
)

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  # Add your query here
  results = $client.query("SELECT * FROM items;").to_a

  {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: results.to_json
  }
end
```